# cannot use regSSM in R-Studio

Tags: r

I'm using RStudio-0.98.1103 with R-3.1.2 on windows machine.
I want to use regSSM and i followed the following documentation -

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/KFAS/docs/regSSM

I've installed KFAS package as followed - 
install.packages('KFAS')
require(KFAS)

tried to run regSSM in R-Studio and i keep getting the following error - 
object 'regSSM' not found

What am I missing here?

Comment: We can only help if you show your code - otherwise it's just guess work what you tried.  Please show your code

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like -

```
install.packages('KFAS')
install.packages('latticeExtra')
install.packages('quantmod')

require(compiler)
require(latticeExtra)
require(KFAS)
require(quantmod)

Kalman.beta <- cmpfun(function(y, X)
{
   model <- regSSM(y = y, X = cbind(1, X), H = NA, Q = diag(NA, 2))
   object <- fitSSM(inits = rep(0, 3), model = model)$model
   KFAS <- KFS(object = object)
   alpha.beta <- xts(t(KFAS$alphahat), index(y))
   colnames(alpha.beta) <- rep(paste(colnames(y), 'vs' , colnames(X)), 2)
   return(alpha.beta)
})
```

and during deceleration of Kalman.beta i'm getting the error "no visible global function definition for 'regSSM' "

In RStudio , under KFAS package help files from some reason i can't see regSSM and i can't find it in any other package.